# How to display HTML through Laravel DataTable?

Tags: php, html, laravel, datatables

I am trying to get some HTML with my dataTable request.

I use Laravel DataTable library. When I get the data, the page displays the HTML as a normal text in the column which I don't want, I wanna display it as a normal HTML.

```
public function suppliers(){
    $Suppliers = Suppliers::getSuppliersView();

    return Datatables::of($Suppliers)
                ->addColumn('operations', '<button id="{{ $serial_no }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>')
                ->rawColumns(['operations'])
                ->make();
}
```

Any help about this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution since a while,

We can use

```
->escapeColumns(['operations'])
```

and set the name of each column we want to display its HTML.

It may help someone else too. Thank you...

Comment: You are my HERO!! Thanks dear :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  $users = $user->all();
    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->addColumn('feature', function($row) {
            return  $row->feature ;
        })->escapeColumns([])
        ->make(true);
```

Comment: You are my HERO!! Thanks dear :)

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Unescaped Data

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, {!! $name !!}.

Try changing your blade tags to

{!! $serial_no !!}

Comment: I just found the solution, and posted the answer. Check it if interested.

Comment: It is not about blade, Rows are going to be displayed through AJAX request, using JQuery DataTables, this can not help in this situation.